# How do I arrange the lines of a txt file with numbers?

Tags: python, for-loop, indexing

```
wordlist = open(r'C:\Users\islam\Desktop\10k most passwords.txt')

for words in wordlist:
    line = (words.split())  
    
    for ele in enumerate(line , 1):
        y = list(ele)
        print(y)
```

The output :

> [1, 'balboa']

> [1, 'bbbbb1']

> [1, 'banks']

> [1, 'badabing']

> [1, 'harriet']

I want to add 1 to the first index '1' in every line to be like that:

> [1, 'balboa']

> [2, 'bbbbb1']

> [3, 'banks']

> [4, 'badabing']

> [5, 'harriet']

Comment: You can merge 2 list like ```list_2 = [list_1] + [list_2]``` , Try : ```y = [1] + y```

Comment: You should enumerate wordlist, not line.

Comment: Do you expect multiple words per line? Otherwise you don't need a second loop.

Comment: Nothing wrong with your code. I get exactly your desired output. [1, 'balboa,']
[2, 'bbbbb1,']
[3, 'banks,']
[4, 'badabing,']
[5, 'harriet']

Comment: @mkrieger1 your method worked ! but all the lists expect last one like this  9994, 'hugohugo\n'] have '\n' in the end of the list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @mkrieger1 said, You should enumerate wordlist, not line:

```
for count, ele in enumerate(wordlist, 1):
    print([count, ele])
```

**Example:**

```
wordlist = ['balboa','bbbbb1','banks','badabing','harriet']
```

**Output:**

```
[1, 'balboa']
[2, 'bbbbb1']
[3, 'banks']
[4, 'badabing']
[5, 'harriet']
```

Comment: same thing worked but got /n in every list